# Javascript (Vanilla) Execution Order inside Function with DOM update and AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I've a piece of JavaScript that gets called when a button is clicked.

The function manipulates some DOM (makes the page opaque, reveals an animation) and then loops through AJAX calls to 'script.php' many times. When that's over it reloads the page, fresh.

My issues is that on Chrome and IE, for the life of me, I can't get the DOM modifications to happen before the AJAX runs and completes. It works fine on Firefox.

I've tried calling sequentially in the code. Nesting each part in a function and in a third, calling each in order.

I've tried to use a promise. Everytime, the AJAX runs and completes, the screen flickers with the DOM mods just before the page reloads.

How is this usually managed?

The problem in a nutshell.

What are some ways I can force Chrome (and Edge) to update the DOM first and then run the AJAX rather than the other way around.

My code is here:

```
function Backup(OrgRowIDs) {

document.getElementById('Overlay').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Overlay').style.display="block";

document.getElementById('ActionWindow').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('ActionWindow').style.display="inline";

function GenerateBackupID () {       

    var Characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';  

    var ID = '';

    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

                var pos = Math.floor((Math.random() * 60) + 1)
                ID = ID + Characters.substring(pos, pos + 1);
    }        

    return ID;

}

function RecordBackupSessionID() {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                        return;      

                    }

                }           

                xhttp.open("GET", "../AJAX/RecordBackupID?backupfile=" + OrgRowIDs[i] + "&backupid=" + BID , false);
                xhttp.send();

            }

for (i = 0; i < OrgRowIDs.length; i++){

    BID = GenerateBackupID();

    RecordBackupSessionID();

    function BackupFiles(i) {

            for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {

                function BackupEndPoints(j) {

                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                            //do something if we want.

                        }
                    }           

                    xhttp.open("GET", "../AJAX/BackupFiles?backupfile=" + OrgRowIDs[i] + "&endpoint=" + j + "&backupid=" + BID , false);
                    xhttp.send();

                    }

                BackupEndPoints(j)    

                }

            }

        BackupFiles(i)

    }

location.reload();

}
```

Comment: Your `One` promise never resolves (because you never call `resolve`)

Comment: Thanks Phil. I'll look into that. I'm editing the question (substantially) in light on notice of an XY problem.

Comment: I've solved it. The problem is essentially a rewording of 'loading animation appears after ajax has run', and there are lots and lots of these asked on SO. I had this on both Chrome and Edge. Thanks to Phil for his debug (I couldn't get that to work, but probably my issue).

Comment: ...cont the solution I used was to wrap the iterator and ajax calls in a setTimeout (function ...(){ ajax goes here },0); wrapper. This hands control back to the browser to update the DOM before the AJAX is run; and this works for asynch a synch executions.